# sharepoint event receiver never fire

Tags: sharepoint

I tried to follow a few examples on how to create sharepoint event receiver.  Most examples are fairly straightforward in instructions.  So I was able to create a sharepoint event receiver project (for example: item adding or site deleting) in visual studio 2010 and deployed to server and site.  I checked the feature and it is activated.  I ran some test like deleting a test site or even uploading a file.  But the test error messages i put in the code never run.  I cannot figure out why the events are never fired.

The following is an example of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace DeletingSite.EventReceiver1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Web Events
    /// </summary>
    public class EventReceiver1 : SPWebEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// A site is being deleted.
       /// </summary>
       public override void WebDeleting(SPWebEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.WebDeleting(properties);
           properties.Cancel = true;
           properties.ErrorMessage = "You cannot ";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers >
      <Receiver>
        <Name>EventReceiver1WebDeleting</Name>
        <Type>WebDeleting</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>DeletingSite.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>

  </Receivers>
</Elements>

Comment: Sorry for the elements.xml looking like that.  Anyway, I saw the dll for the event receiver in the GAC. not sure what this means:  $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$

Comment: $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$ is a placeholder that is  replaced by VS on publishing with full assembly name.

Answer (score 0):

Under Event Receiver item, there would be element.xml file. This file defines how and where your event receiver is attached. Please check if everything is correct within that file.